# Registrarse con Google

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, registro

Quiero hacer un registro de sesion con google, y para ello, lo plantee sencillo de la manera que voy a mostrar abajo. El problema es la variable '$C', se que cuando selecciona los emails, los selecciona todos y no uno en especifico que es el que quiero. Por eso, me gustaria saber como hacer para compararlo con un unico email que sea de ultimo usuario que apreto el boton de registrarse. Si alguno me puede dar una idea, lo agradeceria mucho!

```
<?php
 require_once 'configuracion.php';

 $email= "";
 $name= "";


 // authenticate code from Google OAuth Flow
 if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
 $token = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($_GET['code']);
 $client->setAccessToken($token['access_token']);

 // get profile info
 $google_oauth = new Google_Service_Oauth2($client);
 $google_account_info = $google_oauth->userinfo->get();
 $email =  $google_account_info->email;
 $name =  $google_account_info->name;

 }

$conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","playroom"); 

//Registrarse con google
$C="SELECT `email` FROM `login` ";

if($email == $C){
echo "<h1>Ya se ha registrado previamente. Por favor, inicie sesion</h1>";
}else{
$m= "INSERT INTO `login` (`email`, `usuario`, `Id_usuario`)
VALUES ('$email','$name','')";
mysqli_query($conexion,$m);
};

mysqli_query($conexion,$C);
echo mysqli_error($conexion);
?>
```

Solo quiero que no se repita el email en la base de datos y que funcione como un registro corresponde. Deberia hacer del email una clave primaria? Asi puedo programar que si hay un duplicate entry, le muestra al usuario que ya se registro antes. Eso si, si alguien le parece correcto lo que dije y sabe como hacerlo, le agradeceria que me muestre como hacerlo porque no tengo mucha idea.

Answer (score 1):

El proceso de autenticación usando Google no distingue entre registrarse y login. Es decir, utilizas la misma lógica en ambos casos, por eso el botón dice "continuar con Google".

En ambos casos lo que debes hacer es verificar si el correo del usuario ya existe en tu base de datos. Si ya existe, simplemente lo envías hacia dentro de tu aplicación usando un `header("location: ...")`. Si no existe, lo agregas a la base de datos y luego lo envías hacia dentro (nuevamente, `header("location: ...")`). Si por algún motivo Google no pudo autenticarlo, lo devuelves hacia el formulario inicial y allí si colocas un mensaje de error (algo por el estilo de "No se pudo autenticar su cuenta", o algo así).

Ten en cuenta que antes de enviar al usuario hacia dentro de tu aplicación debes cargar las variables de sesión asociadas al usuario que necesites para trabajar (rol, nombre completo, etc.)

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta!  Lo que pasa es que no quiero que se repita dentro de la base de datos el correo y tampoco sabria como hacerlo, si es posible, enviarias un ejemplo con un codigo? Si no es mucha molestia, igualmente te agradezco por tomarte el tiempo de responderme, muchas gracias!

Comment: En mi perfil puedes ver una URL mediante la cual puedes enviarme un mensaje.